# Using OR operator with if condition in matlab

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab

I have four variables in MATLAB and I want to check if any two of them are over 80. How can I do that using OR operator?

Let's say variables are a,b,c,d

```
 if (at least two of them > 80)

  do something

 end
```

I can do like (a&&b > 80 || a&&c > 80 || a&&d > 80)...... but I think it is not a good way to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array with your 4 variables `[a,b,c,d]`, then compare this array with your threshold value `[a,b,c,d] > 80`. Now you can sum the binary output and check if the sum is bigger or equal to 2.

```
% Dummy variable
a = 50
b = 90
c = 100
d = 20

% Check if there is at least two variables bigger than 80
if sum([a,b,c,d]>80) >= 2
    disp('There is at least two variables bigger than 80')
end
```